# Accessing successive/previous row in R Data Frame

Tags: r

I've recently learned to do a bit of row-based manipulation in R Data Frames, e.g.

```
df<-data.frame(c(1,5,10,21,33,50,73,80,99,102))
output['DaysBetween']<-c(0,df[-1,1]-df[-nrow(df),1])
```

But I dont really understand what's happening there.

I'm also trying to apply some manipulations based on the successive row, i.e. something like:

```
df
Days, DaysSinceLast, DaysToNext
1, 0, 4
5, 4, 5
```

etc

I dont know, even with the previous `['DaysBetween']` mentioned above, how to generate that operation and my attempts to do this have failed.

Can someone explain to me...

a) What is actually happening in the `output['DaysBetween']` logic?

b) How to do the `output['DaysToNext']`?

c) How I then might rank these in order, i.e. generate a new column `output['Ranking']` with the index for where it would come if sorted first to last on `DaysToNext`?(I dont want to actually do this sort for other reasons)

Thanks so much, help appreciated

EDIT:

My first two questions have been solved now, thank you. Ideally, what I want to do next is something like:

```
df
row  value
1  ,   10
2  ,   8
3  ,   15
```

And to take this and produce:

```
df
row  value, ranking
1  ,   10 , 2
2  ,   8  , 3
3  ,   15 , 1
```

When I try to create a copy of my df and then sort it, it seems to be failing, I'm not sure why, but this also seems a bit of an inefficient method to do it?

Edit: Problem has been solved with the inefficient method as described

Comment: By removing first and last element, we are making the lengths same to do the difference between current and next element.  To understand what is happening, check the output of `df[-1, 1]` and `df[-nrow(df), 1]`.  We concatenate with `0` as the length is 1 less than the nrow of df.  This is the same as `c(0, diff(df[,1]))`

Comment: Ah, so df[-1,1] is removing the first element, and df[-nrow(df)] is removing the last element? Thanks!

Comment: Lol@Diff. Of course there's already a pre-built function. Nice.

Comment: if you want the output you wrote, just do: `transform(df, DaysSinceLast=c(0, diff(df[,1])), DaysToNext=c(diff(df[,1]),0))`

Comment: The example is merely illustrative, the actual thing I'm trying to do is more complicated (not much more, its a step-wise evaluation of y() given some parameters y2 and y1) Thanks!

Comment: In testing, diff only seems to return integer values - it works fine if I diff over, say, (1,5,10,15,200) but breaks and returns 0 for (0.5, 0.8, 1.3, 1.7) - how can I get round this? I tried a case of the variable using as.double() but that didnt help

Comment: I get `diff(c(0.5, 0.8, 1.3, 1.7))#
[1] 0.3 0.5 0.4`

Comment: Found the error.

Thanks, I've now cracked (a) and (b) in my problem, dont know how to crack c without creating another data frame, sorting it & assigning a new index based on position, and then re-merging